# GStreamer rtp stream to vlc

Tags: streaming, gstreamer, vlc

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to create a simple rtp stream with gstreamer and display it on vlc.

I've installed GStreamer 0.10.30 and VLC 1.1.3. My only requirement is to use MPEG4 or H.264 codecs.

Right now, I can stream the GStreamer **videotestsrc** through this simple pipeline:

```
gst-launch videotestsrc ! ffenc_mpeg4 ! rtpmp4vpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

which outputs the "caps" needed by the client to receive the stream:

```
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)MP4V-ES, profile-level-id=(string)1, config=(string)000001b001000001b58913000001000000012000c48d8800f50a041e1463000001b24c61766335322e3132332e30, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)365697461, clock-base=(uint)390754204, seqnum-base=(uint)10399
```

I'm also able to display the stream using the following pipeline:

```
gst-launch udpsrc uri=udp://127.0.0.1:5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)MP4V-ES, profile-level-id=(string)1, config=(string)000001b001000001b58913000001000000012000c48d88007d0a041e1463000001b24c61766335322e3132332e30, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)298758266, clock-base=(uint)3097828288, seqnum-base=(uint)63478" ! rtpmp4vdepay ! ffdec_mpeg4 ! autovideosink
```

but when I try to receive the stream with vlc:

```
vlc -vvv rtp://127.0.0.1:5000
```

I get nothing...

Comment: Question: Where is the path to this file, filename and is it a configuration file that you just edited in gstreamer?

Comment: What does the payload=(int)96 mean?

Comment: How can I know your streaming command is using this settings/caps "/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: (...)". Where do you get this information from?

Comment: For those coming in the future: you might get an error saying there's no such element as `ffenc_mpeg4`. Just replace `ffenc_mpeg4` and `ffdec_mpeg4` with `avenc_mpeg4` and `avdec_mpeg4` respectively.

Answer (score 49):

I've solved the issue, it just needs an sdp file like this:

```
v=0
m=video 5000 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
a=rtpmap:96 MP4V-ES/90000
```

and the option "send-config=true" for the rtpmp4vpay element:

```
gst-launch videotestsrc ! ffenc_mpeg4 ! rtpmp4vpay send-config=true ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

and then, it can be played with

```
vlc <filename>.sdp
```

Comment: I've found how to write sdp file for any codec. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTP_audio_video_profile then go to coresponding RFC link that have sample of SDP syntax

Comment: This is the kind of behaviour that deserves multiple upvotes. The question was super relevant to me but without the self answer it would be kind of useless.

Comment: Using gstreamer 1.0 the line should be `gst-launch videotestsrc ! ffenc_mpeg4 ! rtpmp4vpay config-interval=3 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000` Where `config-interval=3` is the interval in seconds sending the config data. `send-config` is now deprecated.

Comment: How to generate SDP file for MJPEG stream? rfc2435 seems too large. Also `rtpjpegpay` don't have option like `send-config`.

Comment: Since using 127.0.0.1 isn't clear, I just thought I would mention: in a multiple machine environment, this would be causing your client (VLC or whatever) to open an inbound port (so possibly firewall rules needed) and the stream would be sending to it.  This solution isn't providing you with a way to easily have multiple VLC clients connect to a single endpoint. (that confused me a bit).

Comment: It will also require the server to define the outbound connection to each client - so no chance of having a URL that any client can connect to.

Comment: https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/Introduction_to_network_streaming_using_GStreamer This was useful to me to figure out the parameters.

Answer (score 27):

How to for H264 and new gstreamer (windows)

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! openh264enc ! rtph264pay config-interval=10 pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

sdp file:

```
v=0
m=video 5000 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
```

for other codec see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTP_audio_video_profile and corresponding SDP example in RFC link

Comment: You mistyped the port number, otherwise it is working - tested but with x264enc (on Linux).. good tip on the RFC

Comment: And the OSX equivalent: `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! vtenc_h264 ! rtph264pay config-interval=10 pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000` (instead of `openh264enc`)

Comment: In my case adding ```h264parse``` after ```openh264enc``` works on Windows;   
```gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! openh264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=10 pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000```

Answer (score 3):

For some of you just check the answers, but not comments below the answers

For GStreamer 1.18.xxx. ffenc_mpeg4 was renamed to avenc_mpeg4(This confuses me alot)
So try command:

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! avenc_mpeg4 ! rtpmp4vpay config-interval=1 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000`

About VLC same as Dave's answer