# gstreamer: cannot launch rtsp streaming

Tags: stream, gstreamer, rtsp

I am new to gstreamer. Although it sounds like a very entry-level question I couldn't find clear answer so far.

I try to launch server like below according to some example.

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 ! udpsink rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test
```

Then I use VLC as client (on the same computer).

```
$ vlc rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test
```

VLC reports error of "Unable to connect...". But if I use "test-launch" in the first step, it works fine.

Another question is besides VLC, I try to launch client like this.

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test ! rtph264depay ! ffdec_h264 ! xvimagesink
```

But gstreamer complains no element "ffdec_h264" and no element "xvimagesink".

For extra info, I installed "gstreamer" and "gst-plugins-base/good/bad/ugly", all from git (1.2 version).

Thank you so much for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ffdec_h264` is from gst-0.10, so you need to use `avdec_h264` in gst-1.0 instead. By the other hand, I use to play `autovideosink sync=false` as pipeline sink in my udp stream.

There is an example code in `gst-rtsp-0.10.8/examples` that can help you with the rstp stream server, but I suggest you receive the stream using `udpsrc` in gstreamer in order to reduce the delay (use `-v` option in the source to see `caps` parameter and configure it in the receiver).

If you want VLC to play your rtsp stream you need to define the .sdp file according to your rtsp stream session.

You should see this question for more info: 
[GStreamer rtp stream to vlc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154983/gstreamer-rtp-stream-to-vlc)

Comment: I give up. I should just use "test-launch" which will serve my testing purpose. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about VLC, but as far the gstreamer launch line goes, you seem to be missing the ffmpeg package. you can probably find it in the same place as you found the other plugins.

Also, replace xvimagesink with autovideosink, which will use any sinks you have available.

Comment: But from this link (http://weeklybuild.com/2013/01/creating-an-rtsp-stream-with-gstreamer/), it seems you can do without ffmpeg stuff, right?