# How to stream video from webcam using Gstreamer?

Tags: windows, streaming, video-streaming, gstreamer, audio-streaming

How to stream video(and if it possible audio too) from webcam using Gstreamer? I already tried to [stream video from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154983/gstreamer-rtp-stream-to-vlc), but I can't stream video from webcam on Windows. **How I can do this?**

---

Client:

```
    VIDEO_CAPS="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H263-1998"
DEST=localhost
VIDEO_DEC="rtph263pdepay ! avdec_h263"
VIDEO_SINK="videoconvert ! autovideosink"
LATENCY=100
gst-launch -v gstrtpbin name=rtpbin latency=$LATENCY                                    \
           udpsrc caps=$VIDEO_CAPS port=5000 ! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_0                   \
             rtpbin. ! $VIDEO_DEC ! $VIDEO_SINK                                     \
           udpsrc port=5001 ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_0                                   \
           rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink host=$DEST port=5005 sync=false async=false
```

Server:

```
DEST=127.0.0.1
VOFFSET=0
AOFFSET=0
VELEM="ksvideosrc is-live=1"
VCAPS="video/x-raw,width=352,height=288,framerate=15/1"
VSOURCE="$VELEM ! $VCAPS"
VENC="avenc_h263p ! rtph263ppay"
VRTPSINK="udpsink port=5000 host=$DEST ts-offset=$VOFFSET name=vrtpsink"
VRTCPSINK="udpsink port=5001 host=$DEST sync=false async=false name=vrtcpsink"
VRTCPSRC="udpsrc port=5005 name=vrtpsrc"
gst-launch gstrtpbin name=rtpbin
            $VSOURCE ! $VENC ! rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_2
          rtpbin.send_rtp_src_2 ! $VRTPSINK 
              rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_2 ! $VRTCPSINK
            $VRTCPSRC ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_2
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use GStreamer 1.3.90 or newer and the ksvideosrc element that is available only since that version.

And then you can stream it just like any other input... the details depend on what codecs, container format, streaming protocol and network protocol you want to use. The same goes for audio, that works basically exactly the same as video.

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/tree/tests/examples/rtp
here you can find some examples that use RTP for streaming. Server side and client side examples, audio-only, video-only or both. And also streaming from real audio/video capture sources (for Linux though, but on Windows it works exactly the same... just with the Windows specific elements for that).

Comment: Now I have not PC, so I can't check is it possible to use not RTP, but UDP myself. Can you say my about this?

Comment: And what do you want to send over raw UDP? Which codec(s) and container format?

Comment: Now it does not really matter for me. I will try to use what will be available.

Comment: Why not RTP then? For everything else it works basically the same way, e.g. if you want to stream MPEG TS you could do: ... ! x264enc ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux ! udpsink host=123.123.123.123 port=4321

Comment: Ok, I think that I can try RTP too. And thanx for the command, if I understand correctly it is a command for send, but I really newbie in gstreamer so I need a full command for sender and receiver. And thanks again!

Comment: Can you give me just two commands for sender and receiver? Thanks!

Comment: See http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/tree/tests/examples/rtp

Comment: Ok, now I trying to use these examples. My client and server in the updated question.
I did not get anyone error and any video. What I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give me advice in my issue or just give two pipelines for sender and receiver?