# Stream webcam video with Gstreamer 1.0 over UDP to VLC player

Tags: udp, gstreamer

I'm trying to stream a webcam video with gstreamer 1.0 over UDP. This is the command I used:

```
gstreamer-1.4.0$ gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video1  ! "image/jpeg,width=1280, height=720,framerate=30/1" ! rtpjpegpay \ ! udpsink host = 10.234.2.65 port = 5000
```

I got receiving via VLC player working with gstreamer 0.1 using an sdp file as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154983/gstreamer-rtp-stream-to-vlc).

How do I achieve the same with gstreamer 1.0?